# JNA Error - Duplicate field name&signature in class file

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, dll, jna

I'm currently trying to call a `C++` `DLL` file in `Java` with `JNA`.

I'm very new to Java and I've been stuck on this problem for the past four hours. I know for a fact that I have a duplicate field of name, I've tried everything but I still can't figure out how to fix it.

It would be great if anyone can provide me with the corrected code and an explanation to the nature of this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in 
class file CSE/CD$SDeviceInfo_NoClass
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at CSE.CD.main(CD.java:25)
```

Java Result: 1

And here is my code

```
package CSE;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class CD 
{
    public interface SDeviceInfo_NoClass extends Library
    {
        SDeviceInfo_NoClass lib = (SDeviceInfo_NoClass)
        Native.loadLibrary("DeviceInfo_NoClass", SDeviceInfo_NoClass.class);

        DEVICEINFO_NOCLASS_API void PopMessageBox();
        DEVICEINFO_NOCLASS_API boolean vDI_SystemPCBVersion(wchar_t *version);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        SDeviceInfo_NoClass.lib.PopMessageBox();
        //^This is Line 25
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JNA mapping code you're actually compiling.  The code currently included won't compile in the first place.

Comment: @technomage I'm not sure what you meant by "mapping code", another tutorial on Kernel32 works with the same layout as this one.

Comment: Interface `SDeviceInfo_NoClass` provides the mapping from Java onto the native library `DeviceInfo_NoClass`.  Thus it is "mapping code".  The library methods in your example look like C declarations rather than Java.